# When are Transaction Finalizers going to be available?

Tags: transaction-finalizers

As part of the API 50 version Salesforce announced [transaction finalizers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction_finalizers.htm).

I personally find this feature so great and look forward to start using it, however it is still in Pilot.

Does someone have any clue or historical reference about how many Salesforce releases does is ussualy take to announce a Pilot feature as Beta?

I undestand GA will take even more time but at least ad Beta we could use it in production orgs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no firm rule for how long a feature in pilot will take to reach GA. It takes a long as it takes.  Fortunately, this is supposed to be [available in Spring 21](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_apex_Transaction_Finalizers_Interface_Beta.htm&release=230&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null), according to the release notes,  and Chris Peterson, who is a Product Manager,  so it's pretty safe to assume it'll be there.  In fact,  you can sign up for a prerelease Spring 21 peg right now and try it out yourself.

Comment: This info is exactly was I was looking for, thank you so much!